# iPhone apps compatibility on iPads

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, appstore-approval

I have a question regarding appstore submission. I have developped an iPhone app, And I have limited it just for portrait. My question is should this iphone app runs on ipads as well even though its an iphone app?

if its not running good on ipad in 1x and 2x mode, will my app be rejected?

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, phone-only apps have to be able to run on an iPad in compatability mode or they will be rejected

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All iPhone apps must run also in iPad. 
You should set it to universal.

Yes if your app doesn't run well on 1x and 2x mode it will be rejected.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 2. 4 PERFORMANCE: HARDWARE COMPATIBILITY Performance - 2.4.1

You have to use Vary for Traits.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

This link help you with understand the adaptative model.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html

And here you have the WWDC explaining how to use Vary for Traits

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Set full screen:

[image]

Last option, Requires full screen in your project properties page, Deployment Info section.

Comment: Should it support for device orientation as well?

Comment: No. You can set it to portrait only. You should also set to fullscreen to avoid problems with multitasking in iPad. You don't need to fit all resolutions.

Comment: How to set it to full screen?

Comment: Thank you. So should I create as a universal app? But I have already created as iphone app.

Comment: No problem... you can change it and adapt for iPad too

Comment: But earlier we could create iphone only spps and simbit the appstore isnt it?

Comment: Yes. Long time ago, if I remember well, since iOS 8 it has changed. Now, you don't need universal apps, but it need to runs on iPad. Is too hard to make it works in iPad only by compatibility (1x,2x mode) so its easier to make the adaptative views using vary for traits. You will see, its not hard.